# Call to undefined function setContext()

Tags: php

I wanna send an email, but when i send it, there is problem like this:
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function setContext() in C:\xampp\htdocs\rapor\admin\mail.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\rapor\admin\mail.php on line 27*

I GET "id" from URL and SELECT with query in **mail.php** page.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require '../config/connect.php';

$kodenilai = $_GET["id"];
$queryKirim = mysqli_query($konek,"SELECT nilai.*, pelajaran.nama_pelajaran, siswa.nama_siswa, siswa.nis FROM siswa, pelajaran, nilai, datakelas, kelas
  WHERE nilai.kode_siswa=siswa.kode_siswa
  AND nilai.kode_pelajaran=pelajaran.kode_pelajaran
  AND datakelas.kode_siswa=siswa.kode_siswa
  AND datakelas.kode_kelas=kelas.kode_kelas
  AND kelas.kode_kelas=nilai.kode_kelas
  AND nilai.kode_nilai='$kodenilai'")or die("gagal".mysqli_error());

$data=mysqli_fetch_array($queryKirim);

$dataNilai['nis']           = $data['nis'];
$dataNilai['nama_siswa']    = $data['nama_siswa'];
$dataNilai['semester']      = $data['semester'];
$dataNilai['nama_pelajaran']= $data['nama_pelajaran'];
$dataNilai['nilai_tugas']   = $data['nilai_tugas'];
$dataNilai['nilai_tugas2']  = $data['nilai_tugas2'];
$dataNilai['nilai_tugas3']  = $data['nilai_tugas3'];
$dataNilai['nilai_uts']     = $data['nilai_uts'];
$dataNilai['nilai_uas']     = $data['nilai_uas'];

    function setContext($data) {
    $postdata = http_build_query($data);

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );
    return stream_context_create($opts);
}

$context = setContext($dataNilai);

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "mail.besp.gq";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "********";
$mail->Password = "********";
$mail->setFrom('info@besp.gq', 'Info');
$mail->addReplyTo('admin123@besp.gq', 'Admin');
$mail->addAddress('ujangujing765@gmail.com', 'ujangujing765');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('mail-temp/content.php', false, $context));
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

In the script above, i set the setContext is data array. is there problem?

Thanks first..

Comment: Where is the function definition? Are you sure you're loading the file in?

Comment: Emm, sorry.. what function is that?

Comment: Make sure that your setContext function is accessible

Comment: i have edit. I put function setContext in.

Comment: And do you still get an error?

Comment: No. That's work very great. But $data cannot read by content.php.